# How to log a stacktrace of all exceptions of rxJava2?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

We need a global handler for **rxJava2** exceptions passed to onError of any subscriber to just log the stacktrace happened in any part of the system.
In the **first** version of rxJava is a `RxJavaHooks.setOnError` method which does exactly this thing.

```
RxJavaHooks.setOnError(throwable -> Log.w(TAG, "rx error", throwable));
```

But in the rxJava2 that class was removed and as they noticed the logic have been moved to `RxJavaPlugins` class. It has some similar named method `RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler`, but actually the invocation purpose is completely different. It handles only **undeliverable** exceptions.
How can i log all exceptions either it is catched by subscriber or not?
I don't really want to attach logger to every particular observable in the system
*Upd*: maybe you have some advice only for android system

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021001/3256989

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way of doing it; you have to install `onSubscribe` or `onAssembly` hooks to all the main reactive types which then wrap the `Subscriber`s in a way that doesn't interfere with internal optimizations unexpectedly.

The extensions project has an [assembly tracking debug feature](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions/blob/master/src/main/java/hu/akarnokd/rxjava2/debug/RxJavaAssemblyTracking.java#L50) which captures the stacktrace of the current thread when flows are assembled and attaches that information in the `onError` exception passing through it (which you actually need).